# Cefsharp works for x64 but no x86 v.108.4.13

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I was running cefsharp v91.1.21 and upgraded NuGet packages:

cef.redist.x64, cef.redist.x86 to 108.4.13
cefsharp.common and cefsharp.winforms to v108.4.130

Prior to upgrading I was targeting x86 and deployed through clickonce without issue.

After upgrading, my winforms project and everything works fine if I target x64 but when I target x86 the application crashes on  `Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);`
. Looking at the crash dump, all I see is:

Unhandled exception at 0x10CC6C48 (libcef.dll)

and the libcef.dll is version 108.4.13

I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot this issue, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Target x86:

CefSharp After Build Diagnostic

CefSharpBuildAction = Content
CefSharpPropertiesLoaded = true
CefSharpTargetDir =
CefSharpTargetDirAnyCpu32 = x86
CefSharpTargetDirAnyCpu64 = x64
CefSharpAnyCpuSupport =
RuntimeIdentifier =
EffectivePlatform =
Platform = x86
PlatformName = x86
Platforms =
PlatformTarget = x86
CefSharpPlatformTarget = x86
PlatformTargetAsMSBuildArchitecture = x86
TargetFramework =
TargetFrameworkVersion = v4.8
libcef.dll exists = bin\x86\Debug\libcef.dll
CefSharpTransformXmlDllPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll
NuGetProjectStyle =
NuGetToolVersion =
OutputType = WinExe
OutDir = bin\x86\Debug\
Prefer32Bit = true

Logging:
[0112/154303.980:ERROR:broker_win.cc(56)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)

Comment: Are you trying to use the 64-bit CEF DLLs in a 32-bit build?  That will not work.   You'll need the 32-bit versions.  Spotify has both for native C++, and your source for CefSharp should have both too.

Comment: There's troubleshooting instructions at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3436#discussioncomment-3946083 edit your original question with the output of the `CefSharpAfterBuildDiagnostic` msbuild target.

Comment: added some clarity, I was previously running v91.1.21 without issue targeting x86 and just upgraded the NuGet packages to the latest version and now only the x64 works. all of the files are found, but libcef is throwing an exception but only targeting x86.

Comment: There were changes to the nuget packages in since version 91. Please provide the output of `CefSharpAfterBuildDiagnostic`. Also  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample is provided as a working example and is kept up to date with the latest version. Can you test with one of the solutions changing the platform to target `x86`. Also check the log file https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file for errors

Comment: The Minimal Example works correctly. Added the logging information.

Comment: If the minimal example works then it suggests there's something specific to your project, the debugging from MSBuild looks ok at first glance. Have you tried performing a clean checkout of your project from source control after you upgraded? Occasionally the `bin` folder ends up in a mixed up state with files from different versions. Alternatively just delete your bin/obj folders for all projects in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the most consistent way to get this to work:

```
//add to app.config file with text editor and insert the following
<runtime><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><probing privatePath="x86"/></assemblyBinding></runtime> 
// after the <configuration> line. 

//and add the settings to cef:
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = ExecutingAssemblyDirectory + "\\x86\\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"; 

//add to .csproj
<PropertyGroup>
<CefSharpBuildAction>Content</CefSharpBuildAction>
<CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>true</CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>  <CefSharpPlatformTargetOverride>AnyCPU</CefSharpPlatformTargetOverride>
</PropertyGroup>
```